# 90-ball bingo - shortest path to winner-ticket

Tags: mysql

For a 90-ball bingo game engine in which I know how all the tickets look, I need to calculate the shortest path to a winner-ticket, based on the numbers that have been called for the given game.

For each game we expect to generate around 1000 tickets, and each play will have three contests: "1 row", "2 rows" (on one ticket, obviously) and "full ticket".

The path is defined as the numbers that I need to call in order to have a winner-ticket - for a given contest.

The table layout is very straight forward:

```
A ticket belongs to a game - it has three rows
A ticket row belongs to a ticket - it has 5 fields
A ticket row field belongs to a ticket row - it has one content field
```

Called numbers are also registered per game.

ticket:
id
game_id

ticket_row:
id
ticket_id

ticket_row_field:
id
ticket_row_id
content

called_number:
game_id
called_number

All fields are integer types.

I found it easy enough to get the shortest path for the contests "1 row" and "full ticket" where I can group by ticket_row_id and ticket_id respectively.

Here is how I do it for the 1 row contest:

```
select 
    r.ticket_id, 
    count(content) path_distance, 
    group_concat(content order by content) path
from 
    ticket t
    inner join ticket_row r
        on r.ticket_id = t.id
    inner join ticket_row_field f
        on f.ticket_row_id = r.id
    left join called_number n
        on n.game_id = t.game_id
        and n.called_number = f.content
where
    n.called_number is null
group by 
    ticket_row_id
having 
    path_distance < 4
order by 
    path_distance;
```

My problem is: How do I find the shortest path for the contest "2 rows on the same ticket" using MySQL (which does not support windowing functions)?

To describe it in more technical terms: For each ticket I want to find the sum of the count of the field-contents not matched by called_number, but only for the two rows with the least amount of missing fields. Tickets should be ordered so that those with the fewest missing fields come first.

I would like the result to look like this:

```
+-----------+---------------+------------+
| ticket_id | path_distance |    path    |
+-----------+---------------+------------+
|        12 |             3 |   14,32,78 |
+-----------+---------------+------------+
|         9 |             4 | 2,58,76,89 |
+-----------+---------------+------------+
... etc
```

Comment: Your solution for the 1 row contest will list every ticket up to three times - even if it already has a full row. I'm not sure if you want to say: ticket 12 needs the numbers 14,32,78 to win the one-row-challenge if it already has won it. Nevertheless, you can get your two-row-result by joining a 2nd row too (add the three joins a 2nd time, and a condition `r1.ticket_row_id < r2.ticket_row_id`) and `group by r1.ticket_row_id, r2.ticket_row_id`. If you need your path to be ordered, it will get a little more complicated (you can probably do it by joining a dummy table with all 90 numbers).

Comment: @solarflare The query in the example returns the rows that has a path_distance shorter than 4, even if that means returning multiple rows from a single ticket - that is by design. But I am not sure I fully understand how your suggested additional join should look. Could you provide an example?

Comment: I mean: add the joins `inner join ticket_row r2 on r.ticket_id = t.id and r1.ticket_row_id != r.ticket_row_id inner join ticket_row_field f2 on f2.ticket_row_id = r.id left join called_number n2 on n2.game_id = t.game_id and and n2.called_number = f2.content` and adjust your conditions and selects (e.g. add `distinct`). If you provide a (simplified) table structure (with the fields in your qurey) and some sample data I can do it.

Comment: I can't get your suggestion to work. I've resolved it myself using two views representing rows with missing and rows with no missing numbers respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The folllowing seems to be the way to go:
First we create a  couple of views so to make the actual select query easier to comprehend

This first view represents rows that are already completely filled - meaning that all 5 numbers have also been called.

```
create or replace view filled as
select 
    r.ticket_id, f.ticket_row_id, 0 path_distance
from 
    ticket_row_field f
    inner join ticket_row r
        on r.id = f.ticket_row_id
    inner join ticket t
        on t.id = r.ticket_id
    inner join called_number n
        on n.called_number = f.content
group by ticket_row_id
having count(*) = 5;
```

The other view represents rows that are not completely filled

```
create or replace view incomplete as
        select 
            r.ticket_id, f.ticket_row_id,
                coalesce(filled.path_distance, count(content)) path_distance,
                case when 
                    filled.path_distance is not null then 
                    '' else 
                    group_concat(content order by content) 
                end path
        from 
            ticket t
            inner join ticket_row r
                on r.ticket_id = t.id
            inner join ticket_row_field f
                on f.ticket_row_id = r.id
            left join called_number n
                on n.game_id = t.game_id
                and n.called_number = f.content
            left join filled
                on filled.ticket_row_id = f.ticket_row_id
        where 
            n.called_number is null or filled.ticket_row_id is not null
        group by 
            ticket_row_id;
```

Then we use the following select query to get the tickets we need, including their path (= the missing numbers)

```
select 
    r1.ticket_id, r1.path_distance + r2.path_distance distance_sum, concat(r1.path, ',', r2.path) path_combined
from 
    incomplete r1
        inner join incomplete r2
            on r2.ticket_id = r1.ticket_id
where 
    r2.ticket_row_id < r1.ticket_row_id
order by 
    distance_sum
limit 5;
```